# Spring cannot inject Bean in class that implements Quartz Job

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to send an email from a class that implements Quartz Job, in order to do that I have to @Autowire the IEmailService inside the class.

Here is the method I use to create a Quartz Job:

```
@Override
    public Boolean sendInfoEmail(ManifestationProp manifProp, ServletRequest request) throws SchedulerException {             
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String token = httpRequest.getHeader("jwt_token");  
        if(token == null) {
            System.out.println("(ManifestationPropDaoImp) - TOKEN NULL");
            return false;
        }           
        String email = tokenUtils.getUsernameFromToken(token);      
        User user = userDao.findUserByEmail(email);         
        if(update(manifProp) != null) {             
            Scheduler sc = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
            sc.start();
            JobKey jobKey = new JobKey("Job_"+manifProp.getId(),"group1");
            if(!sc.checkExists(jobKey)) {                                   System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Scheduling a Job for Manifestation Prop with ID - "+ manifProp.getId());
                System.out.println("Current time - " + new Date());
                System.out.println("Scheduled time - NOW" );
                System.out.println("User - "+ user.getEmail());
                System.out.println("Manifestation Prop - "+manifProp.getName());    
                JobDataMap jdm = new JobDataMap();
                jdm.put("manifProp",manifProp);
                jdm.put("user", user);
                JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(QuartzInformUser.class)
                                                .withIdentity(jobKey)
                                                .usingJobData(jdm)
                                                .build();
                Trigger t = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("SimpleTrigger_"+manifProp.getId()).startNow().build();
                sc.scheduleJob(jobDetail, t);
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
            }else {
                System.out.println(" *** Job_"+manifProp.getId()+" already exists! *** ");
            }
            return true;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Could not update manifestation prop!");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Here is the code of the class which implements Job interface:

```
@Service
public class QuartzInformUser implements Job{

    @Autowired
    IEmailService emailService;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {   
        try {
            JobDataMap dataMap = arg0.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();  
            User user = (User)dataMap.get("user");
            ManifestationProp manifProp = (ManifestationProp)dataMap.get("manifProp"); 
            System.out.println("USER: "+user);
            System.out.println("MANIFESTATION PROP: "+manifProp);
            emailService.informUser(user,manifProp);            
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Quartz Job gets created perfectly fine, the problem is in the class `QuartzInformUser`. Spring does not inject `IEmailService` into the class, therefore the field `emailService` is `null` and i get the following exception:

[image]

If anyone has any idea how can i fix this issue I would really appreciate the help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about using the brand-new [Spring Boot Quartz starter](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-quartz/2.0.1.RELEASE)? Unfortunately I haven't had enough time to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the spring helpers/implementations of the various Quartz components, so that the jobs you create will be managed by spring.

- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-quartz
- http://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule

... are two good starting points (although you'll want to make sure the documentation you look at is appropriate for the version of spring you're using; spring-boot for example has a starter for scheduling/quartz)

Comment: These links helped me a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory` in your project? This will add the support of autowiring to quartz jobs.

```
public final class AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        beanFactory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();        
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
        final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
        return job;
    }
}
```

You also need to create a jobFactory and set the application context to your quartz jobs. This should be in a `@Configuration` class

```
 @Bean
 public JobFactory jobFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
 {
     AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
     jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
     return jobFactory;
 }
```

(Just copy and paste this class in your project)

Comment: I have just created this class. Would you please be kind enough to let me know how does this class fit into my code?

Comment: I added some more code. You will need the configuration to enable the support of autowiring to your quartz jobs